# How to hook on a WooCommerce checkout field?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Each field of the default Woocommerce form checkout has this markup:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field" data-priority="10">
     <label for="billing_first_name" class="">Name&nbsp;
           <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
     </label>
     <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="given-name">
     </span>
</p>
```

Now, I want:

1. Wrap each field in a wrapper like `<div class="single-field-wrapper"><p [...] </div>`
2. Wrap the first two fields, 'billing_first_name' and 'billing_last_name' in a wrapper like `<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper"> [...] </div>`

To achieve this, I've tried to use the filter hooks made available by `function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null )` called in `form-billing.php` template in this way:

```
<?php
        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
            if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $fields[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
                $field['country'] = $checkout->get_value( $field['country_field'] );
            }
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        }
    ?>
```

So in `functions.php` I wrote:

```
function change_woocommerce_field_markup($field, $key, $args, $value){

  $field = '<div class="single-field-wrapper">'.$field.'</div>';

  if($key === 'billing_first_name') {

      $field = '<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper">'.$field;
   }
  else if ($key === 'billing_last_name') {

      $field = $field.'</div>';
   }

   else {
      $field = $field;
   }

    return $field;
   } 

  add_filter("woocommerce_form_field","change_woocommerce_field_markup", 10, 4);
```

Unexpectedly, I get this markup:

```
<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper">
       <div class="single-field-wrapper">
            <div class="single-field-wrapper">
            [here there are all the fields, one under the other ]
            </div>
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div>   
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
       <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
 </div>
```

Anyone can explain why this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Can you show us the code that adds the div tag with the "single-field-wrapper" class?

Comment: Sure, I missed it, now I've edited the post. It's in `change_woocommerce_field_markup` function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hook `woocommerce_form_field`, there is hook `woocommerce_form_field_{$args[type]}` [(doc)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

`$args[type]` can be (look [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2147) for available options):

- text,
- checkbox,
- country,
- ...

Code below will wrap '*billing_first_name*' and '*billing_last_name*' fields in a wrapper like `<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper"> [...] </div>`.

```
function change_woocommerce_field_markup($field, $key, $args, $value) {

   $field = '<div class="single-field-wrapper">'.$field.'</div>';

   if($key === 'billing_first_name')
      $field = '<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper">'.$field;
   else if ($key === 'billing_last_name')
      $field = $field.'</div>';

    return $field;
} 

add_filter("woocommerce_form_field_text","change_woocommerce_field_markup", 10, 4);
```

It will also wrap `text` type fields with `<div class="single-field-wrapper">...</div>`.
**BUT**
some text fields that have own type (like state or email) require additional hooks, for example:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_form_field_country","change_woocommerce_field_markup", 10, 4);
add_filter("woocommerce_form_field_email","change_woocommerce_field_markup", 10, 4);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Above code works in WC-v3.3.7.

In WC-v3.4.xx you get this:

```
<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper">
    <div class="single-field-wrapper">
        <div class="single-field-wrapper">
            [here there are all the fields, one under the other ]
        </div>
    <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
    <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
    <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div> 
    ....
    <div class="single-field-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

because javascript sorts form rows inside `.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper`. Look at the file `woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/address-i18n.js`, from line 99.
JS finds all HTML tags with ".form-row" class inside wrapper, takes parent of **first** item (tag with class `.form-row`), sort items by priority and insert them into **previously selected parent element**.

For the test, change in file `address-i18.js`, in line 99
   `var fieldsets = $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper, ...`
to
   `var fieldsets = $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper2, ...`
and upload as `address-i18.min.js`.

**Removing JS sorting is not a solution, it is just a test.** Whithout sorting by JS you will get this:

```
<div class="first-and-second-field-wrapper">
    <div class="single-field-wrapper">
        <p class="form-row ..." id="billing_first_name_field"> <label for="billing_first_name"> ... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-field-wrapper">
        <p class="form-row ..." id="billing_last_name_field"> <label for="billing_last_name">... </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-field-wrapper">
   <p class="form-row ..." id="billing_company_field"> <label for="billing_company">...  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null )` has - see at the end of source code - `/**
   * General filter on form fields.
   *
   * @since 3.4.0
   */
  $field = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field', $field, $key, $args, $value );` See line 2663 https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php.

Comment: Moreover, your code unfortunately doesn't make any change to the actual behavior.. See ![this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSVJt.png)

Comment: OK, I checked only in the documentation, and there was no this filter.

Comment: Ok, but what about the main topic? Still I can't understand why your and my solution don't work...

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! It's INCREDIBLE how the Javascript part of Woocommerce is totally undocumented, unpredictable and difficult to hook into....

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the exact same issue that I hadn't spotted before. I originally opened [this ticket on the WC GitHub](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/7501) back in 2015, so it's great that they added the filter... but the JS-based reshuffling is a pain. However, [nmr's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309788/17826) pointed me in the right direction:

As the JS reshuffle works on the `.form-row` element, you just need to a) remove it from the field you want to wrap, and b) add it to your own new field wrapper:

```
function change_woocommerce_field_markup( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {

    //  Remove the .form-row class from the current field wrapper

    $field = str_replace('form-row', '', $field);

    //  Wrap the field (and its wrapper) in a new custom div, adding .form-row so the reshuffling works as expected, and adding the field priority

    $field = '<div class="form-row single-field-wrapper" data-priority="' . $args['priority'] . '">' . $field . '</div>';

    return $field;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'change_woocommerce_field_markup', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. In my case, I also added an ID with `$key` to fine tune the styling of the new wrapper: `$field = '<div class="form-row single-field-wrapper" id="' . $key . '_wrapper" data-priority="' . $args['priority'] . '">' . $field . '</div>';`

Comment: I found out the this breaks the `woocommerce-invalid` class in the original wrapper (`<p>`). To solve this, a custom checkout.js is needed, where you change the jQuery selector to find the <p> again, on line 203 (`$parent = $this.closest( '.form-row p' ),`)